# Changing canvas background

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have HTML5 canvas drawing app and I need to change it's background color when user clicks a button.

Background-color on canvas is working on user-side, but user can save the image to server and I'm exporting canvas data using canvas.toDataURL('image/png'). Problem is, background color of canvas is not included, it only sends data user drawn.

I thought about putting big retangle over whole canvas, but that overwrites all drawings already made. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the background after you already have drawn something on the canvas, you could add another canvas with the same size and with "display:none" - then, before sending the image, just fill the temporary canvas with your main canvas element's background color from the CSS, then draw the main canvas onto the temporary one.
Finally, send to server the composite from the temporary canvas rather than the bitmap of the main canvas that has the transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing any code, but: You need to draw the background using it's context. Setting the background using CSS will as you already discovered not include it when you extract the image.

Canvas is simply put two parts: the canvas *element* itself and its *bitmap*. Using CSS affects the element but not the bitmap. Therefor, you need to update the bitmap usually through its context or using the pixel buffer for it to become a part of the bitmap.

Do the following:

- At initialization, draw the background using for example `fillRect()`
- Draw your remaining graphics on top
- Extract using `toDataURL()`